# Serialize/deserialize from sqlalchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I am using sqlalchemy 0.7 for a project of mine an I am wondering if there is a builtin module in order to serialize/deserialize a persistent entity (xml or json). I would like to implement an export/import procedure and I am guessing if there something already built on top of sqlalchemy.

Thanks

Comment: That's a very old version of SQLAlchemy. There's [marshmallow](https://marshmallow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), but you have to figure out which version works for you because the latest marshmallow-sqlalchemy requires 0.9.7.

Comment: I suppose Marshmallow is too redundant and hard to use in every day life. This solution needs much less code: https://github.com/n0nSmoker/SQLAlchemy-serializer

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [PickleType](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/type_basics.html)
It looks like you could do something like

```
obj = Column(sqlalchemy.types.PickleType, nullable = False)
```

in a declarative_base class (or include that column in a table declaration).  Then the python pickle module will be used to serialize and deserialize your object.